# Excel Autofill issues

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a calendar excel sheet that has week number and month numbers, but it also has ID fields for week and month. So I have week 1 which has 7 days in it with each date having a week ID of 40. If I try the auto fill to drag down it ends up going 40.1, 40.2 or some things similar. Don't use excel often. Is it possible to get it to just repeat the ID for the Week? (for example every 7 days a new id is generated?)

Thanks

Comment: what was wrong about `=WEEKNUM(date)`?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the weeknum(date), but its the unique ID that needs to change. for example

Week 51 would be WeekID 51, Week 52 would be weekID 52, Week 1 Would be WeekID 53. Its not related to the actual week number, its a unique ID field that increases as the weeks change regardless of the year/month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice trick to get repeated value *x* times, then increase value by 1 and repeat *x* times, ... is to use rounded-down division of row numbers:

```
=INT((ROW() - row_offset) / nr_of_repeats) + initial_value
```

e.g. values for following formula:

```
=INT((ROW() - 2) / 7) + 40

A1  Header
A2  40
A3  40
A4  40
A5  40
A6  40
A7  40
A8  40
A9  41
A10 41
...
```

Replace `ROW` by `COLUMN` or relative reference to a cell with Day_ID as appropriate.

It might be a good idea to replace the formulas with (Paste special) values after you compute the correct numbers..